# Forcing error in TypeScript compile with void return

Tags: typescript

With the following code:

```
function foo() : void {
   // do something
}

var f = foo();  // why no error here?
```

This does not produce a compiler warning/error even though the foo function has been declared to **not** return anything.

Another case that I'd like to prevent is:

```
if (foo()) {

}
```

I'm building an API to be used by other developers, and TypeScript works well encouraging type safety and often helps to catch common JavaScript errors that otherwise would only be caught in testing rather than at compile time. This case though isn't apparently handled though as it would be in other languages like C#. The developers often will be customers, and may not have as much experience, so I want to make the platform as robust as possible, and catch as many issues before the code is deployed.

Is there some reasonable way to structure the code to prevent other code from attempting to use the `undefined` result of a function that has no return value? If `foo` doesn't return anything, I'd rather code only can call it as `foo();` and not inadvertently expect a valid return value when doing an assignment (or similar execution).

Other programming languages would often catch this type of code structure at compile time (and display a warning/error).

Comment: How did you discover this?  Is this a simplified example of real code that you discovered was broken by accident at runtime when you would have expected it to be caught by the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: It's a simplified example of something real.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `void` is a *valid* TypeScript type declaration. E.g the following is valid

```
var f:void;
```

However it is not *useful* as a variable type.

From the language spec (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf):

> NOTE: We might consider disallowing declaring variables of type Void as they serve no useful purpose. 
>   However, because Void is permitted as a type argument to a generic type or function it is not feasible to 
>   disallow Void properties or parameters.

**Update:** 
As pointed out by Ryan : https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/479664200323579904 You don't get much *additional* typesafety if `f:void` was disallowed. You can't use `f` in a meaningful way e.g. the following are all compile errors.

```
var f:void;

f.bar; // error 
function bar(f:{}){}
bar(f); // error
var baz:{a?:number} = f; // error


// Only allowed cases
f = undefined;
f = null;
```

Curious about your real world case though.

**Update based on question update:** Unfortunately I don't see a way to get the compiler to prevent this, since *anything* is allowed in a JS/TS if statement. Perhaps you want a `boolean` only truthy/falsy restriction.

```
if (f()) {

}
```

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to declare a function as **not** returning a value though. `void` is unfortunately not like `void` in other programming languages (which made it a curious choice by the language authors).

Comment: @WiredPrairie see update. What safety are you missing

Comment: I added a little more detail. The simple summary is that I want the code to be as robust as possible and the compiler to catch as much as possible. While there are certainly tests and QA that could ideally catch this, I want this to be caught without additional effort.

Comment: Another case this won't fail at is function f(a: any){} (which would be the case with external libraries). I agree with WiredPrairie, this should be caught at assignment, not at usage... But I guess there was some motivation behind the design choice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you try:

```
var f:number=foo();
```

It will return the error you're looking for. I think an untyped variable defaults to "any" which makes it not check typing.

Link [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20foo%28%29%20%3a%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20//%20do%20something%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20f%3anumber%20=%20foo%28%29;%20%20//%20why%20no%20error%20here?):

Comment: Yes, that would work if you declared a type. But it's not required to declare the type as the type is implicit in the declaration. The `f` variable is actually of type `void`.